# NodeJS edit binary file than return file to user

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, stream

I have method get with URL, where i want to read binary file, edit it (rewrite some bytes in specific address (skip bytes)) than i want to return it to user without saving (changing) file on filesystem).

I have this piece of code to edit file, but i don't want to change file on filesystem and return file to user (user want to download it).

```
router.get('/downloadFile', function (req, res, next) {
    var id = req.query.id;
    var buf = new Buffer(id);
    var file = '/opt/file.exe';

    var filename = path.basename(file);
    var mimetype = mime.lookup(file);

    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
    res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);

    var wstream = fs.createWriteStream(file, {flags: 'w', encoding: 'binary'});
    wstream.once('open', function(fd) {
        wstream.write(file, buf, 5262720, buf.length, );
        wstream.end();
       // here i want to send file to user
    });
});
```

**UPDATE:** 
Piece of code above editing file on file system in real time. So when i open write stream and do write operation - this changes immediately apply to file on file system. I've found this way to do what i want, and now i ask - is this properly way?

```
var content = fs.readFileSync(file);
var cnt = 5262720;
for (var i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
    content[cnt] = buf[i];
    cnt++;
}

res.end(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just send the content, without saving the file.

With this snippet the user will download the file from the browser.

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");

    http.createServer(function(req, res) {

            res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=file.exe');
            res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-msdownload');

            //Your logic here...

            res.end(content); //The modified file content.

    }).listen("8080", "0.0.0.0")
```

Comment: Content it is file. But I have file and I can open file write stream, write bytes, in result of this I have stream or file?

Comment: The modified file content isn't the file, I understood that you already did your logic of editing the file, and all you want to do is send it to the user. If you have the content, just send it as I showed you ;)

Comment: @dikkini Do you have the modified content?

Comment: I add in my question full piece of code to edit and download file